# WPF window in a main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have few WPF windows.

When I want to open a new window, I will close the current one, and load a new one:

```
ProductMain productMain= new ProductMain();
productMain.Show();
this.Close();
```

I know you can put user control into window.

Can I load the window in a main window?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that by setting the Window's owner property. To get the main window use:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow
```

After that, you can set the [owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) of the ProductMain window:

```
ProductMain productMain= new ProductMain();
productMain.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
productMain.Show();
```